# Sticky footer hiding content

Tags: html, css

I made the following sticky footer using CSS. The bottom page content is currently hidden behind the footer (see the attached screenshot). How can I adjust my CSS so that all of the body content is visible and the footer remains stuck to the bottom of the browser window? Thank you!

[image]

CSS:

```
.fo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:65px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #eaeaea;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
```

Comment: you have given your footer a height of 65px. Just give your content div a margin-bottom of 65px and all is fine

Comment: @SvenBieder exactly that was the case

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I came across this answer out on the internet in the past. Works great:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
/* IE 6 and down:
#container {
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. When the content was short, footer stayed at the bottom of the screen, as the content expanded, footer moved and was still at the bottom of the screen without overlapping the text.

Comment: Footer's position should be `fixed` not `absolute` or it will move when the content expands as described by @aspnetdeveloper

Answer (score 40):

You can create a clear div and give it a height.

```
.clear { clear: both; height: 60px; }

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER CONTENT</div>
```

Height being whatever you need to keep content above the footer, eg. taller than the footer. If the footer is 50px; tall, I do 60px; for the height in the clear div. So when I scroll, the footer stays in place but as I get to the bottom the content that is flowing from behind the footer has room to get pushed above the footer without being covered. Super simple, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with this as well when I came up with my own solution. I set my footer to have a `height` of `10%` :

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  **height:10%;**
  width:100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and my content to have a `bottom margin` of `11%` :

```
#content{
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  color: #99FFCC;
  height: 80%;
  padding:30px;
  **margin-bottom: 11%;**
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who had the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

This can help,
at the end of the HTML:

```css
.spacer{
  margin-bottom: 110px; /* how high is your footer */
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div  class="spacer"> . </div> /* you need to type someting, simple point can do the trick */
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the other solutions pointed me in the right direction, but because I am using Angular Material all I had to do was add layout="column" and it worked great

```
    <div id="container" layout="column">
       <div id="header"></div>
       <div id="body"></div>
       <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add an empty div right ahead the footer and I named it with an id (div-spacer):

`<div id="div-spacer"></div>`

Then I've created a simple line of code that grabs the last element's height and set it to the div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#div-spacer').css("height",$('.card-transaction:last').css("height"));
});
```

With this solution the last element is always visible!

Answer (score 0):

I propose adding scroll-padding-bottom in HTML.

`scroll-padding-bottom: 2em;`

Answer (score 0):

According to your question the height of your footer is 65px, So lets make a tailor made solution for your problem

Wrap the body content within a div

Select that particular div within the css and add `margin-bottom: 65px;` (you can replace 65px with a higher value if you need some more space at the bottom)

Answer (score -7):

I just added the br tag 5 times at the end of the body text to create some extra white spaces. It helped me.

> *sometimes keeping it simple works!!!*