# Content flowing over sticky footer

Tags: css, html

I have a wrapper for my website and am currently coding a fully functioning website for the first time in HTML5 and am having problems getting my footer to "stick" to the bottom of the wrapper.

When I fiddle with the CSS I am sometimes successful in getting the footer to stick to the bottom of the wrapper however if the content of the wrapper (articles/sections) is over the fold of the browser then the content within the wrapper breaks the wrappers edge as the height of the wrapper only seems to be the height of the resolution of the screen (768 in this case). So the content ends up going infront of behind the footer.

Anyway code:

```
     <footer>

    <p><small>&copy; Copyright blahdeblah 2013. All Rights Reserved.</small></p>

    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}

   #wrapper {
height:100%;
margin:0px auto;
position:relative;
width:900px;
}

footer{
background:#B4B4B4;
border:5px solid #FFFFFF;
height:50px;
line-height:45px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}
```

So essentially my wrapper isn't expanding with the content :(

Comment: can you please show this issue in Jsfiddle?

Comment: Have a look at [this question + answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881548/sticky-footer-hiding-content?rq=1). Should solve your problem. BTW: The web is full of tutorials about "Sticky Footer" - you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your wrapper's height is set to 100%. It means that the height of the wrapper will not exceed the height of the user's screen, even though the content in it might. removing the 'height:100%' part should solve your problem. If the user's screen will be shorter than the content in the wrapper, a scroller will appear.

Comment: Not removing but changing to `min-height: 100%` is the correct way ...! And the <body> needs a padding-bottom equal to the height (here 50px) of the footer.

Comment: Can't the height be lower than 100%?

Comment: No, because then the footer won't stick at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, Netsurfer that seems to have resolved the problem. Quick one. M article just above the footer has a curved border and two floating sections within it. The floats have been cleared via a div but the bottom part of the article thats above the footer hides behind the footer. I've tried adjusting the margins to no avail.

Comment: All contents "above" the footer need to be in a container element (I guess the element with the id #wrapper in your case) and this element needs a pdding-bottom equal to the height of the footer, so that there is no visible content behind the footer (only the padding area). If you still having problems then you should set up a jsFiddle, please.