# How to make footer not sticky

Tags: html, css

How to make footer not sticky ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9rda0j0/2/)

```
 #footer {
   bottom: 0;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't set it to `position : fixed;`

Comment: Oh and don't set the middle section on `overflow : auto;`

Comment: Removed both and now sidebar is moving when scrolling and footer is in the middle now, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9rda0j0/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "not sticky"? If you want your footer to be at the bottom of your page but after your content and not over, you don't have to use any position kind or if you use it, use "position: absolute".

After that, we're on HTML5 now so you don't have to use  or  but directly use  and/or

Comment: I mean I don't want the footer to always appear, I want it to appear only when I scroll down, If I remove position I get other issue like sidebar is moving when scrolling and is also over the footer.
Thanks

Comment: It's easy. Don't use any position for your #footer but use "position: fixed;" for your sidebar.

Comment: And as it's HTML5. You can use "<header>" instead "<div class="header">", same for the footer and your left bar (make it as a "<nav>") and your right bar (make it as a "<sidebar>")

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I changed div header & div footer to just header & footer, I also changed the left side which is bunch of links to <nav> but kept the right tag the same as <div class="right"> because it is where the main content is.

Comment: I also removed the position from footer but I'm not sure where I should put the position: fixed; I mean by sidebar you mean the left side <nav> or the right side <div class="right"> ?

btw here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9rda0j0/7/) after update

Comment: The answer here fixed my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881548/sticky-footer-hiding-content