# Footer bar hiding content

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I m working on an ionic application, and I have this code:

```
<ion-footer-bar  >
    <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
  <a class="tab-item" href="#/admin">
    <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-a" style="color:blue" ></i>
  </a>

</div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

when I have a long list, this ion-footer hide the content, and it doesn't stay at the bottom of the page. I search and I  find some solutions like this one: [Sticky footer hiding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881548/sticky-footer-hiding-content), but it doesn't work for me. How can I do please!

Comment: Please make a working fiddle.

Comment: you can hide the footer using using `display:none;` and when scroll reaches to bottom which you can get using scroll event on `content` tag. You have to calculate whether the scroll reaches to bottom or not. if yes then you have to show the footer again

Comment: I get what you mean, but how can I do this event on content please!